# Appending query string params dynamically

Tags: php, query-string

I have a webpage which allows users to filter results. Once a filter is set it is appended to the URL eg: `www.testsite.com?show=active`. The results are broken into several pages (simple pagination) once a user clicks a certain page the page is also appended to the user like `www.testsite.com?page=3`. The problem I have is that after applying a filter and then clicking a page number the URL should be `www.testsite.com?show=active&page=3` but instead the URL turn into just `www.testsite.com?page=3` loosing the previously set filter.

I set the href to the pagination links as follows `<a href='?page=3'>3</a>` and to the filter links as `<a href="?show=active">Active items</a>`

Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` WILL PRESERVE IF.. YOU CAN APPEND IT AFTER `page` varaible

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

To get the current query string

You can prepend it to your links like

```
 '?' . <?= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?> . '&show=active'
```